# codeigniter working on local server but : syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in model

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to upload my codeigniter website on 000webhost server . but its giving me a syntax error

> syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in
>   /home/a4703701/public_html/application/controllers/update.php

but its working correct on localhost.

the error is in model my model is

```
public function user($id=NULL)
    {
       if($id=='')
         {
            $q  = $this->db->get('user');
            if($q->num_rows()>0)
            {
                return $q;
            }
         }
      else 
         {
            $q  = $this->db->get_where('user',['id'=>$id]);
            if($q->num_rows()>0)
            {
                return $q->row();
            }
         }
    }
```

any idea how to remove this error ?

Comment: Replace `['id'=>$id]` with `array('id'=>$id)`. The first is a way to create arrays in Javascript and PHP 5.4+ (?) while the later is the proper way to create arrays in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost certainly not running PHP 5.4 or newer but are trying to use syntax only available in those versions.

```
['id'=>$id]
```

is shorthand array syntax and was introduced in PHP 5.4. You need to replace it with:

```
array('id'=>$id)
```

to be backwards compatible with prior PHP versions.